# nginx reverse proxy cache if backend down

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I currently have a reverse proxy setup with 5 mins caching. However, I'd like it to use the cache if backend is down and not let the cache expire until it's back up. If the backend is up, however, the cache should refresh every 5 mins. Is that possible?

Here's my config:

```
    proxy_pass $backend;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
    proxy_buffering off;
    client_max_body_size 0;
    proxy_read_timeout 20s;
    proxy_redirect off;
    fastcgi_cache_bypass $fastcgi_skipcache;
    fastcgi_no_cache $fastcgi_skipcache;
    fastcgi_cache cache;
    fastcgi_cache_valid any 5m;
```

Comment: You could have a dedicated cache server and utilize the cache as a `backup` in your config. That way when the primary is unavailable, the backup with the cache is used.

Comment: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache_use_stale

Comment: And, BTW, fastcgi_* directives has no effect on proxy_pass, so you have no cache at all